# Upload image to an ftp server through android app

Tags: java, android, upload, ftp, imageview

Hey I have an `android` app that pick a image from gallery and show it on an `ImageView` , I want to upload the picked image to my `ftp server`, I tried using `SimpleFtp` library but it just didn't worked so I deleted it , how can I do it?

here is the code of loading the image:

```
public void loadImage(View view)
{
    loadedImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.upload_image1);
    Drawable drawable = loadedImage.getDrawable();
    if(drawable.getConstantState().equals(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.camera_icon).getConstantState())) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "SelectPicture"), SELECT_PICTURE);
    }
    else
    {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, ShowImage.class);
        i.putExtra("uri",selectedImageURI.toString());
        startActivity(i);
    }
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {


             selectedImageURI = data.getData();
            loadedImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.upload_image1);
            loadedImage.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            Glide.with(this).load(selectedImageURI)
                    .into((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.upload_image1));


        }

    }
}
```

Comment: "I tried using SimpleFtp library but it just didn't worked" what exactly didn't work? Did you try to debug it and find out what the issue was?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to work with api - Retrofit2.
Try [this](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-how-to-upload-files-to-serve)